# Passing multiple parameters to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

OK I have a method that takes two parameters.

```
public IActionResult Checked(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
```

I have a button in the view:

```
<form asp-action="Checked" asp-route-fromDate="2020-06-14" asp-route-toDate="2020-07-01" method="post">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info form-control"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; All Checked</button>
                </form>
```

For simplicity sake I have hard coded the dates. All I get is a 404 error page not found without it hitting the method.

"No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44377/Admin/CurrentAccountCheck/Checked/2020-06-14/2020-07-01"

I have tried adding:

```
[Route("Admin/CurrentAccountCheck/Checked/{fromDate?}/{toDate?}")]
```

And even:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "CACC",
                pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=CurrentAccountCheck}/{action=Checked}/{fromDate?}/{toDate?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

in the startup file.
What I am I doing wrong?

I have found that the issue lies in the method:

```
            public IActionResult UpdateFlag(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newfund = _db.Fund.Where(p => p.AccountId == 1).Where(p => p.Date >= fromDate).Where(p => p.Date <= toDate).ToList();
            foreach (var item in newfund)
            {
                Fund saveFund = new Fund { FundId = item.FundId };
                //_db.Attach(saveFund);
                saveFund.IsChecked = true;
                saveFund.CreatedBy = item.CreatedBy;
                saveFund.CreatedDate = item.CreatedDate;
                saveFund.LastModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                saveFund.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                _db.Update(saveFund);
            }
            
            _db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Updated.";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { FromDate = fromDate, ToDate = toDate });
        }
        else
        {
             ViewBag.Message = "Failed ! Please try again.";
             return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { FromDate = fromDate, ToDate = toDate });   
        }

    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the _db.Update(saveFund) i can see that the requisite data is there but when I let it continue I get the 404 - page not found and it does not save the changes.

Comment: You shouldn't be using routes to pass data, they are not the same thing.

Comment: I've take out all route mapping and still get 404 error

Comment: The problem is the _db.Update so put a Try/Catch around it and check the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting error from `SaveChanges` as when you get `entities` with `var newfund = _db.Fund.Where(p => p.AccountId == 1).Where(p => p.Date >= fromDate).Where(p => p.Date <= toDate).ToList();`, it will be tracked by `dbcontext`. And then you are creating new object `saveFund` to update for `entity` which is already being `tracked`.

To solve you can use `AsNoTracking()` extension method while `retrieving` entities. Also you can simplify your `Where` conditions. Use code like below.

```
var newfund = _db.Fund.AsNoTracking()
                 .Where(p => p.AccountId == 1 && p.Date >= fromDate && p.Date <= toDate)
                 .ToList();
foreach (var item in newfund)
{
    Fund saveFund = new Fund { FundId = item.FundId };
    //_db.Attach(saveFund);
    saveFund.IsChecked = true;
    saveFund.CreatedBy = item.CreatedBy;
    saveFund.CreatedDate = item.CreatedDate;
    saveFund.LastModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    saveFund.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

    _db.Update(saveFund);
}

_db.SaveChanges();
```

---

**Approach 2** Don't use `AsNoTracking()` but simply `modify` already `retrieved entities` instead of creating new object. You don't need to use `_db.Update` either because `entity` are already being `tracked`.

```
var newfund = _db.Fund
                 .Where(p => p.AccountId == 1 && p.Date >= fromDate && p.Date <= toDate)
                 .ToList();
foreach (var item in newfund)
{
    item.IsChecked = true;
    item.LastModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    item.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Karan I have just independently arrived at the same solution as Approach 2